# Convert string to date in dataweave

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and I am looking to convert the following date `2017-03-02T17:30:31.377Z` into the following format `Thurs, 1 Mar 2017 17:30:31 GMT` in Dataweave.

The Dataweave code currently looks like this:

```
{
    datetime: "2017-03-02T17:30:31.377Z" as :datetime {format: "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"}
}
```

but I am getting an error saying that it cannot coerce a string to a date.  How can I change the date above to the correct format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referring the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation, we have to define the certain timezone instead of only `Z`. In this example, we have to transform the input date: from `2017-03-02T17:30:31.377Z` to `2017-03-02T17:30:31.377+0700`. And then continue to change it into the expected format.

1. Transform the input date: `("2017-03-02T17:30:31.377Z" replace "Z" with "+0700")`
2. Convert the input date from String to DateTime: `as :datetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}`
3. Change the date format: `as :string {format: "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"}`

Complete expression:

```
{
    datetime: ("2017-03-02T17:30:31.377Z" replace "Z" with "+0700") as :datetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"} as :string {format: "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to I get it to show the timezone as GMT as should show when using lowercase z?  It still shows errors when I try format: "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"